Выбор архитектуры для Webassembly
Разрабатываю приложение на Blazor Webassembly, с очень большим фокусом на клиентскую реализацию, большинство сервисов у меня идут как asm, а на бэк приходится лишь пару тройку контроллеров и пару таблиц в бд.
Я столкнулся с проблемой выбора архитектуры и подходам к ее реализации. Поскольку до этого я писал только бэк и работал с Rest API - я не совсем понимаю как располагать клиентские сервисы в коде, ведь они независимы от бэка и используются только в качестве Webassembly.
Хотелось бы услышать предложения по структуре архитектуры.
